# Error in runing grails project after making some modification

Tags: grails, netbeans, groovy

So the project was runing in a good way till i made some modification (which i dont remember where ) when i tried to reopen the project and run it ,  it gave me the output below :

```
 :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileGroovy FAILED

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 10.624 secs
Error |
Gradle build terminated with error: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details. (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

i've tried to clean the project but it fail like the build ,  and i have no idea why this is happening cause i'm a newbie in grails and groovy .
i'am using netbeans as ide and grails v 3.0.0

sry for the bad english

Comment: Try adding `--stacktrace` when you run the app

Comment: thx for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used file history to make it back to what it was , and it work .

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2B5k9.png